# How does a high speed relate to the word "drive"?

Tags: meaning

a meaning and an example of "to drive" from [ahdictionary.com](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=drive):

> to move along or advance quickly:
> **(1)** *We could hear the trucks **driving** along the highway*.

Does (1) mean the trucks were just moving?:
**(2)** *We could hear the trucks **moving** along the highway*.

Does (1) mean the trucks were not just moving but they were moving with a high speed?:
**(3)** *We could hear the trucks **moving fast** along the highway*.

Or maybe (1) may mean both (2) and (3)?

---

I'm asking it because I want to understand: if I say "some vehicle is driving", does it necessarily mean a high speed of that vehicle?

Comment: @Lambie Read the question one more time. It's not difficult to see it's the dictionary that suggests the meaning relating to speed, not me.

Comment: Precisely, "driving" there is not drive as in I drive a car. It is a bit unusual in that it means: to move along or advance quickly. So, it works that way. The player was driving the ball down the field really fast. Like that. But it provides the definition: "o move along or advance quickly" So why ask it??

Comment: Counter-upvoted to dismiss the meaningless downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. According to the Oxford dictionary (NOAD), the noun "driving" has the following meaning:

> the control and operation of a motor vehicle.
> Example: "he was convicted of reckless driving"

I find it very odd that the speed is even mentioned in your meaning, as a vehicle can also drive very slowly. When you're using the word driving, it doesn't mean it's driving in a high speed.

Comment: Yes, to have drive is to have high energy. But driving a truck means it's not parked. "We could hear the trucks driving along the highway" is not a good example for "advance quickly:"

Comment: In cases like "the wind drove into their face" (another AHD example), "drive" implies force or power. But there are numerous other meanings in the dictionary involving vehicles that don't involve force, speed, or anything beyond not sitting still.

Answer (score 1):

"The truck is driving" is not correct English, at least not in any dialects I'm familiar with. Vehicles don't drive, people do; the vehicles *are driven*. "The truck is being driven on the highway", "they are driving the truck on the highway".

It's worth noting that "drive" can also metaphorically refer to something being moved very fast by other means; "he **drives** the ball into deep left field" refers to the batter propelling the fast-moving baseball.

Comment: Turns out that drive can just mean to move quickly, as in the wind drives the leaves over the road. It's hard to "hear" due to interference from I drive a car.

Comment: Or, @lambie, just to cause to move, independent of speed. Consider “With only three blows of his hammer he **drove** the nail home” or indeed, “This tool is called a screwdriver because we use it to **drive** in screws.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum That is a different usage.

Comment: @lambie, okay. But in that case, the wind’s driving leaves is a different usage from a person’s driving a truck.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum No one is disputing drive a truck versus the wind driving something are different. The OP asked about something that means: to move along or advance quickly, which is confusing **as the phrase comes right after the word truck**  but is ultimately correct since the meaning is to move long quickly, In the OP's question no one is driving a truck...

Comment: @Lambie, exactly. OP asks whether *drive* implies high speed, and my comment illustrates that, no, *drive* can mean “just cause to move, independent of speed.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum But not here as shown by the dictionary definition. Why are you contesting that??

Comment: I would argue that "[vehicle] is driving" is a common enough substitution for "a person is driving that vehicle." As in "Look out! That car is driving right at us!" or "Trucks can't drive on this street." It would be seen as hair-splitting to say "Of course; trucks can't drive at all; they have to be driven by a human." We use the same extension when we say "that plane is flying" or "that boat is sailing."

Comment: Meanwhile, let's not confuse the OP further by bringing "drive" as a *noun* into it.

Comment: @AndyBonner As I said, that substitution is not common in my experience. I would get the meaning, of course, but it would sound strange to me. Possibly a dialectical difference. Fair point that the noun usage could be confusing.

Comment: How does this answer the question about the meaning of "drive" in the given context?

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence in that dictionary is a problem.

Here's two good definitions with OK sample sentences from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive):

> **1 a :** to dash, plunge, or surge ahead rapidly or violently
> *rudely drove past her*
>
> **2 a :** to operate a vehicle
> *learned to drive at the age of seventeen*

The sample sentence you found in AHD *could* be read to have either meaning, but without any other context, it would always be understood to be **2a**, not **1a**.

I can invent a context where **1a** might apply naturally:

> Our car broke down on the side of the highway. We tried flagging someone down, but they all just **drove** right past us, indifferent to our plight.

Even then, it's maybe 50-50 which definition a reader would understand.